# How do I multiply a specific row of values by a list of weightages in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with columns of stock with mean and std as indexes

```
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'st1':[0.016981, 0.053512],
        'st2':[0.021479, 0.067820],
        'st3':[0.057370, 0.117693]
        }
 
# Creates pandas DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['mean',
                                'std'])
```

|  | st1 | st2 | st3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mean | 0.016981 | 0.021479 | 0.057370 |
| std | 0.053512 | 0.067820 | 0.117693 |

I also have a list of weights

```
weight = [(5,90,5),
          (6,4,90),
          (10,10,80)]
```

I need to apply this to a formula:
2*(correlationStock1Stock2)*(Standarddeviation of Stock 1)*(Standarddeviation of Stock 2)*(weight of Stock 1)*(weight of stock 2)
+
2*(correlationStock1Stock3)*(Standarddeviation of Stock 1)*(Standarddeviation of Stock 3)*(weight of Stock 1)*(weight of stock 3)
+
2*(correlationStock2Stock3)*(Standarddeviation of Stock 2)*(Standarddeviation of Stock 3)*(weight of Stock 2)*(weight of stock 3)

basically the formula is 2 * correlation of stock 1 and 2 * weight of stock 1 and 2 * standard deviation for stock 1 and 2. for all the stocks added. so 1,2 + 1,3 + 2,3

the standard deviation is given as std in the table.

that tests all the different weightages, where corr_st1_st2 is correlation of stock 1 and 2, std is the value in the std row and weight is from the list, in the order of the tuple inside.

How do i find the correlation of the different stocks? Also, what would be the best way to get the formula that gives the largest value?

Comment: Can you write the formula properly? Or maybe share a link of the formula?

Comment: Hi, basically the formula is 2 * correlation of stock 1 and 2 * weight of stock 1 and 2 * standard deviation for stock 1 and 2. for all the stocks added. so 1,2 + 1,3 + 2,3. The weight list is also in the order of the stocks.

Comment: And I suppose the correlation between stock 1 and stock 2 is the correlation of columns `st1` and `st2`?

Comment: sorry i didnt clarify that. yeah it is the correlation of the columns of st1 and st2.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I think I have made a code that does what you asked for.

---

Firstly I store the stock data in a variable by the name `df` and convert the weights to a `pandas` dataframe and store this inside `weights`.

What I've assumed is that the `weights` variable has **3 columns** because each value in each row corresponds to the column of the same index, and it has **3 rows** because you want to try different weight values for each stock.

So the code I've written would first try the weight values in the first row, get the value from the formula using those weights, then move to the second row and do the same.

---

Then I made a `formula` function which can calculate the formula value for the stocks you enter.

*To find the correlation between two lists, we can use `corrcoef` function from `numpy` which here is stored as `np`.*

```
def formula(series_1, series_2):
  formula_vals = []

  corr = round(np.corrcoef(df[series_1], df[series_2])[0][-1], 2) # Finds the correlation coefficient between the two stocks.
  std = df.loc["std", [series_1, series_2]] # Finds the standard deviation of the two stocks.
  
  for index in weights.index:
    weights_0 = weights.loc[index, [series_1, series_2]] 

    formula_vals.append(2 * corr * std * weights_0)

  return pd.DataFrame(formula_vals, index = [f"weight {i + 1}" for i in range(len(weights))])
```

Running the function gives us a table that looks like this:

|  | st1 | st2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| weight 1 | 0.535120 | 12.20760 |
| weight 2 | 0.642144 | 0.54256 |
| weight 3 | 1.070240 | 1.35640 |

---

Then I use the `combinations` function from `itertools` to find the possible combinations of the stocks with us and pass each combination inside the function we just created. I store the output of each iteration inside the `formula_dfs` list.

```
combs = list(combinations(df.columns, 2))
formula_dfs = []

for comb in combs:
  formula_dfs.append(formula(comb[0], comb[1]))
```